# JTable, add dynamically lable in concrete cell by MousClick

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have the task, to add the image in the concrete column and raw in the jTable. I have tried to make with setCellRendered, but it does not work correct. Maybe somebody had the same task.
I have tried to make via DefaultTableCellRenderer but now can not understand how can i call this Renderer for concrete cell, not column, for example [3][4]
    public Frame1() {
        initialize();
    }

```
/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 364, 385);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    table = new JTable();
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            Point point = event.getPoint();
            JTable target = (JTable)event.getSource();
            int column = table.columnAtPoint(point); 
            int row = target.getSelectedRow();
           table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setCellRenderer(new ImageRenderer());
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(table, "Column header #" + column + " is clicked");
        }
    });
    table.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, SystemColor.menu, null));
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
            {null, "", null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
        },
        new String[] {
            "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column"
        }
    ));
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(50);
    table.setBounds(0, 0, 350, 350);
    table.setRowHeight(50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(table);
}
```

}

```
class ImageRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
  JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
  ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("green-glossy-ball.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(50, 50, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
      boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    lbl.setIcon(imageIcon);
    return lbl;
  }
```

}

Comment: As i understood when we click on cell this cell should show image, but does it need to show image after you select another cell?

Comment: Yes, i must make a Simple Play "Connect Four".  If i click in a column, the ball must fall down till the first free cell. Now i try to understand how to work with tables and Events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified example from oracle.com. It shows icon on selected cell. Please, look at:

```
/*
 * SimpleTableDemo.java requires no other files.
 */
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {

    private static final String ICON_IMAGE
            = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/scafer31000/bubble-circle-3/16/GameCenter-icon.png";

    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
            "Last Name",
            "Sport",
            "# of Years",
            "Vegetarian"};

        Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith",
                "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
            {"John", "Doe",
                "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Sue", "Black",
                "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Jane", "White",
                "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Joe", "Brown",
                "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
        };

        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        java.awt.Image image = null;
        try {
            URL imageLoc = new URL(ICON_IMAGE);
            image = ImageIO.read(imageLoc);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleTableDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ImageRenderer(icon));
        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
     * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private class ImageRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        private final JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
        private final ImageIcon imageIcon;

        public ImageRenderer(ImageIcon imageIcon) {
            this.imageIcon = imageIcon;
            lbl.setIcon(imageIcon);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component result = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (hasFocus && isSelected) {
                result = lbl;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for a custom renderer.

Comment: @Lena you're welcome! if it's what you're looking for you can vote on it or set as best answer if it is wrong i will try to change it

Comment: @camickr Probably you're right, can you post some example?

Comment: @Lena, this is not how to use a renderer. Data should be stored in the TableModel. A renderer is then used to display the data from the TableModel in the JTable. This code completely bypasses the TableModel an is not an example of how a renderer should be used with  a JTable.

Comment: @camickr  Could you please explain how does tablemodel relate with tablemodel? especially in scope of MVC pattern? Do you suggest to mix data layer with presentation layer? If you added some examples of "right" usage renders it would be perfect

Comment: You already have an example of using a renderer since you copied the code from the Swing tutorial (and I provided a link to the tutorial in my answer). The renderer should be using the "value" parameter to renderer the data. The code you posted completely ignores that parameter, which means you are ignoring the data stored in the TableModel.

Comment: Ok, i see your point and you're absolutely right. But i don't understand what for i have to use the "value" parameter. We just need to show icon and  it  means there is no interaction with data.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a custom render.

What you need to do is:

1. Add an `Icon` the to the `TableModel`
2. Override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of the `TableModel` to return `Class.Icon` and the table will use the default Icon renderer.

If you ever do need a custom renderer then check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for more information and working examples.

```
table.setBounds(0, 0, 350, 350);
table.setRowHeight(50);
frame.getContentPane().add(table);
```

Don't use a null layout!!! Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Also you need to add the table to a JScrollPane in order for the columns headers to display. Again, the examples from the tutorial will show you how to do this. So read the tutorial and download the demo code.

Comment: @Lena, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.